# Showing validation error when submitting with javascript on a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I found an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_max_min) at w3schools, where you can enter a date with given `max` and `min` attributes.

If I enter a date outside of the specified range and submit it, I see:

[image]

It says: "value must be 31-12-1979 or earlier"

Now I believe that this works because the `<input type="submit">` is the way to submit this form here.

However, how can I show the same error/validation message if instead of `<input type="submit">` I use `<button id="bool-submit">Submit</button>`?

Comment: What you tried to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your form by id and then submit and check if all the fields are valid manually with an onclick:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
      <body>
      <form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
        <label for="datemax">Enter a date before 1980-01-01:</label>
        <input type="date" id="datemax" name="datemax" max="1979-12-31"><br><br>
    
        <label for="datemin">Enter a date after 2000-01-01:</label>
        <input type="date" id="datemin" name="datemin" min="2000-01-02"><br><br>
    
        <label for="quantity">Quantity (between 1 and 5):</label>
        <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5"><br><br>
        <button id="bool-submit" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
      </form>
        
        <script>
        function submitForm() {
          if (!document.getElementById("myForm").checkValidity()) {
              return;
          }
          document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
        </script>
        
      </body>
</html>
```